# Соединить две строки и вывести резульат

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, у меня есть две строки:

```
stroka1 = input()
stroka2 = input()
```

Вводные данные:

```
qwertyuiopasd
fghjklzxcvbnm
```

Как мне объединить (сложить) эти строки в одну и вывести её?

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
```

Comment: А если у меня два числа, как их сложить?

Comment: @Андрей без дополнительных библиотек (типа numpy) никак https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif :) Я сейчас обедаю, позже подготовлю вопрос-ответ

Comment: @Андрей `>>> from operator import add
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 6
>>> add(a, b)
11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операция объединения строк по-умному называется **конкатенацией**. В Python для конкатенации используется оператор `+` (плюс):

```
s1 = 'qwertyuiopasd'
s2 = 'fghjklzxcvbnm'
print(s1 + s2)
```

Результат:

> ```
> qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
> ```

Можно положить результат в переменную и вывести уже её:

```
s1 = 'qwertyuiopasd'
s2 = 'fghjklzxcvbnm'
s3 = s1 + s2
print(s3)
```

Comment: Что тут происходит? У тебя истерика?)

Comment: а как числа складывать?